# In mocha, How to wait for the end of an asynchronous test before executing another test?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocha.js, chai

In mocha I have two  test :

- the first one test if an async method get a value as it should :
- the second one test if when getting a value, this first method has 'cached' (I have an internal mechanism for that) a value, so also async.

So I need to make sure that my first test is fully done (meaning my first async method for getting a value is fully done) before executing the second one.

Here is my code :

```
it('Should return a valid value ', () => {
    myService.check('value', (success) => {
        expect(success.isValid)
    });
})
it('Should put the value in cache', () => {
    return myService.getCached('value').then(result => {
        expect(result).to.be.ok;
    })
})
```

The issue is that the second 'it' is launched before the first one is done...

I can use timeouts e.g. :

```
it('Should return a valid value ', () => {
    myService.check('value', (success) => {
        expect(success.isValid)
    });
}).timeout(5000)
it('Should put the value in cache', () => {
    return myService.getCached('value').then(result => {
        expect(result).to.be.ok;
    })
})
```

But I don't like that, it's not 100% reliable and I consider that between two tests we should not wait with a fixed time value !

Is there a better way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make your test be independent and self-fulfilling. So, if you want to test your cache, you should cache the value and check in the cache for the value, like this:

```
it('Should put the value in cache', () => {
    myService.check('value1', (success) => {
        return myService.getCached('value1').then(result => {
            expect(result).to.be.ok;
        })
    });

})
```

If you rely on other tests running before this one, you are:

- Going to run into issues if someone moves code around
- Going to run into issues if the test before it for some reason fails. You do not want the dependency on the other test passing

Comment: Why I did not think of this ? ^^ It's simple and work quite well, thanks :)